# jQuery find(':focus') not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, onblur

I'm making a widget that slides in and out of view on `hover` with `showTracker` and `hideTracker` functions. I want to prevent it from sliding out of view if it contains a focussed form element though, so I've got this going:

```
function hideTracker(){
  if($('#tracker').find(':focus').length == 0){ 
    $('#tracker').stop().hide();    
  }
}
```

Cool. Now it doesn't hide if the mouse happens to move out if there's a field in focus. Unfortunately, that also means that when the field does lose focus (and it's time for the widget to hide again) it just stays there. The unHover event has been and gone.

So I added this:

```
$('#tracker *').blur(function(){
  hideTracker();
});
```

And that works too - with one little bug that I need help with!

If the focus moves from one element within the tracker to another which is also within `#tracker`, the tracker hides. I figured that `if($('#tracker').find(':focus').length == 0)` would return false, given that the next form element has focus, but I guess it doesn't.

Is it the case that .blur() fires before the next element attains focus?

How can I get around this?

Comment: why not just add the blur to your tracker div? you only want to hide it if you lose focus from its fields, irght?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the blur event isn't fired on a div when focus leaves one of its child inputs.

Comment: ah yeah i remember now. anyway, you could also try to check if your input is inside #tracker. if($(this).parents("#tracker").length) dont hide, else, hide

Comment: For now, I've found that adding a .focus() event that shows it again (and using .stop(true, false) on both show and hide) works ok, but adding extra hooks to undo a bad call isn't as tidy as just preventing the thing from hiding in the first place...

Comment: IMHO, it's not a bad call. you just have to check if your input is inside the tracker and that's not a bad hook. it's a prevention measure to not call your hidetracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. Utilising the .focus() event rather than .blur() was a clever way to look at it. Unfortunately, it does raise a couple of browser problems, and I couldn't get any of the above working very robustly.

In the end I decided to use `setTimeout(hideTracker, 100);` to allow the focus() event to take place before the count of focussed elements within tracker was evaluated. Not ideal, but it's working well and the delay is fairly imperceptible.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
$('body *').focus(function(){
    if(!$(this).is('#tracker *') && $('#tracker:visible').length != 0) hideTracker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yikes. Tricky. Yes, what's happening is:

1. `mousedown`: old form element gets the `blur` event. `$(':focus').length == 0`.
2. `mouseup`: new form element gets the `focus` event. `$newFormElement.is(':focus') == true`.

This is an improvement:

```
$('#tracker').focusout(function() //basically like $('#tracker, #tracker *').blur(), but "this" is always '#tracker'
{
    if(!$(this).is('#tracker:hover')) //for some reason plain old :hover doesn't work, at least on the latest OS X Chrome
        hideTracker();
});
```

But it's not perfect. It only really works if you use the mouse. If you use tab to move between fields (or some other possible mechanism) while your mouse is not hovering over `#tracker`, it won't work.

---

Here's another attempt. It's a bit...hackier. The gist is that, instead of handling the `blur` event, you handle the `focus` event of the second thing that's focused. But! What if you click something that can't be focused? Blank space on your page? Then no `focus` event is fired.

Okay. So the trick is: put a `tabindex="0"` in your root `<html>` tag. This means that there is always *something* that can be focused. So there's no way to focus on nothing (at least, I don't think so).

Then you can do this:

```
$('*').live('focus', function(e)
{
    if(!$.contains($('#tracker')[0], this)) //if the new thing you focused on is not a descendant of #tracker
        hideTracker();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Eh? So yeah, that's a certified hack. But it's a tough problem, and that's the best I can come up with at this hour.